# Change Bibliography heading fontsize with elsarticle-num

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, titlesec, bibliographystyle

I have selected the bibliography style `elsarticle-num` for my thesis, which employs the `report` document class and a main document font size of `11pt`.

But one of the requirements is that the font size of headings cannot be more than `13pt`.

I can't seem to find a working solution to change the font size of the Bibliography heading.

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Section Heading Format:
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{20}\bfseries \selectfont}

%Chapter Heading Format:
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \reset@font
        \vspace*{35\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \par
        \fontsize{13}{15} \scshape \@chapapp{} \fontsize{13}{15}\bfseries \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{1\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vspace*{15\p@}
        \fontsize{13}{15} \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Open Text}
    \section{General Info}
    These pages contain information about OpenText \dots\ trademarks\cite{a1} \dots
    
    OpenText maintains this Web site as \dots\ copyright pages.\cite{a2}
    
    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the same format for the Bibliography heading as for the chapters.

The file `references.bib` contains the following entries:

```
@misc{a1,
    author    = "Denis Auroux",
    title     = "18.02SC Multivariable Calculus",
    howpublished = "  Massachusetts Institute of Technology: MIT OpenCourseWare: \url{https://ocw.mit.edu}",
    year     = "2010",
    month    = "Fall",
    note     = "License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA.",
}

@phdthesis {a2,
    author = "Kollmannsberger, Andreas",
    title = "Heating characteristics of fixed focus laser assisted {Thermoplastic-Automated Fiber Placement} of {2D} and {3D} parts",
    type = "Dissertation",
    school = "Technische Universität München",
    address = "München",
    year = 2019,
    keywords = "AFP, Thermoplastic Automated Fiber Placement, Thermal simulation, in situ consolidation, laser heating"
}
```

Kindly Help. Thanks!

Comment: The main issue is that wheras you've defined a chapter header style for *numbered* chapters (such as the one generated by `\chapter{Open Text}`), you have not (yet) done so for *unnumbered* chapters. (The header of the bibliography chapter employs the formatting laid out of unnumbered chapters.) Do please tell us what, according to the formatting requirements you must satisfy, unnumbered chapter-level headers are supposed to look like.

Comment: Same as the numbered chapters. `13pt` and `bold`.

Comment: But what about the first line of numbered chapter headers: Do you want to keep "CHAPTER", with horizontal rules above and below, and just omit the (nonexistent) chapter number? Or should the first line be deleted entirely?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The heading itself has to be plain i.e; without the heading "CHAPTER" and the horizontal rules (above and below). The text style needs to be `13pt` and `bold`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, you've provided a style for numbered chapters, but not for unnumbered chapters. (The bibliography header employs the style of unnumbered chapters.)

You thus need to add the following code:

```
% style of unnumbered chapter headers
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \reset@font
        \vspace*{35\p@}%
        \fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}
```

immediately below the code chunk for `\def\@makechapterhead`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{report}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{a1,
    author    = "Denis Auroux",
    title     = "{18.02SC Multivariable Calculus}",
    howpublished = "Massachusetts Institute of Technology: 
                   MIT OpenCourseWare: \url{https://ocw.mit.edu}",
    year     = "2010",
    month    = "Fall",
    note     = "{License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA}",
}
@phdthesis{a2,
    author  = "Kollmannsberger, Andreas",
    title   = "Heating characteristics of fixed focus laser assisted 
              {Thermoplastic-Automated Fiber Placement} of {2D} 
              and {3D} parts",
    type    = "Doctoral Dissertation",
    school  = "Technische Universität München",
    address = "München",
    year    = 2019,
    keywords= "AFP, Thermoplastic Automated Fiber Placement, 
              Thermal simulation, in situ consolidation, laser heating"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\usepackage{titlesec,xurl}

%Section Heading Format
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries \selectfont}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
%Chapter Header Formats
%Style of numbered chapter headers
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \reset@font
        \vspace*{35\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \par
        \fontsize{13}{15} \scshape \@chapapp{} \fontsize{13}{15}\bfseries \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \par
        \vspace*{1\p@}%
        \hrule
        %\vskip 40\p@
        \vspace*{15\p@}
        \fontsize{13}{15} \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}
%Style of unnumbered chapter headers
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \reset@font
        \vspace*{35\p@}%
        \fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}
\makeatother % <-- don't forget this instruction

\begin{document}

\chapter{Open Text}
\section{General Info}
These pages \dots\ trademarks\cite{a1} \dots\ pages.\cite{a2}
    
\newpage
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How were you able to display certain words of the entries in upper case?
When I compile my code, it displays "18.02sc" and "2d" and "3d".

Comment: @VaradKulkarni - I changed `title = "18.02SC Multivariable Calculus",` to `title = "{18.02SC Multivariable Calculus}",` , etc. Encasing words in curly braces prevents them from being converted to lowercase by BibTeX's "sentence style" (which is in force for the `elsarticle-num` bib style).